# Assigning a 'Value' Parameter to an Ethereum Transaction

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, metamask

I am trying to assign a value of 0.05 Ether to the value parameter for an Ethereum transaction as described in the code below.  I do not understand how to convert 50000000000000000 Wei (0.05 Eth) to the format described '0x29a2241af62c0000'.  Please could someone advise me on how to convert 50000000000000000 wei to this format and what is it exactly?

```
//Sending Ethereum to an address
sendEthButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ethereum
    .request({
      method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
      params: [
        {
          from: accounts[0],
          to: '0x2f318C334780961FB129D2a6c30D0763d9a5C970',
          value: '0x29a2241af62c0000',
          gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
          gas: '0x2710',
        },
      ],
    })
    .then((txHash) => console.log(txHash))
    .catch((error) => console.error);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`0x29a2241af62c000` is the hexadecimal expression of the decimal number `187500000000000000`.

You can use the native JS method `toString()` to convert a decimal number to its hexadecimal form.

```
'0x' + (50000000000000000).toString(16)
```

returns

```
0xb1a2bc2ec50000
```

Or if you want to use web3, there's the [numberToHex()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-utils.html#numbertohex) method.

Answer (score 1):

```js
"0x" + Number(Web3.utils.toWei("0.05", "ether")).toString(16)
```

I think this is the more accurate way to achieve, and it works for me, first convert your value to wei then to hex